# Jupyter notebook getting command not found

Tags: python-3.x, windows, jupyter

```
$ pip install jupyter
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeabl
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in c:\users\nagesh\appdata\roaming\py\python39\site-packages (1.0.0)


$ jupyter
bash: jupyter: command not found
```

after completion of installation process ,while getting this above error in system.

Comment: Provide more information, like are you running it on Windows ?